# PowerShell create nested JSON

Tags: json, powershell

I'm trying to create a JSON object in PowerShell so I can use it in a python script.
I've had mixed results, I'm trying to compress this into one command so I can just run in from my python script

```
ForEach ($disk in (Get-Partition).DiskNumber | select -Unique | Sort-Object)`
{ConvertTo-Json @{$disk.ToString()=`
ForEach ($part in (Get-Partition -DiskNumber $disk).PartitionNumber | Sort-Object)`
{@{$disk.ToString()=Get-Partition -DiskNumber $disk -PartitionNumber $part | `
ForEach-Object {ConvertTo-Json @{PartitionNumber=$_.PartitionNumber;DriveLetter=$_.DriveLetter;Offset=$_.Offset`
}}}}}}
```

This is the output I get:

```
{
    "0":  [
              {
                  "1":  "{\r\n    \"DriveLetter\":  null,\r\n    \"Offset\":  17408,\r\n    \"PartitionNumber\":  1\r\n}"
              },
              {
                  "2":  "{\r\n    \"DriveLetter\":  \"F\",\r\n    \"Offset\":  135266304,\r\n    \"PartitionNumber\":  2\r\n}"
              }
          ]
}
{
    "1":  [
              {
                  "1":  "{\r\n    \"DriveLetter\":  null,\r\n    \"Offset\":  1048576,\r\n    \"PartitionNumber\":  1\r\n}"
              },
              {
                  "2":  "{\r\n    \"DriveLetter\":  null,\r\n    \"Offset\":  315621376,\r\n    \"PartitionNumber\":  2\r\n}"
              },
              {
                  "3":  "{\r\n    \"DriveLetter\":  null,\r\n    \"Offset\":  419430400,\r\n    \"PartitionNumber\":  3\r\n}"
              },
              {
                  "4":  "{\r\n    \"DriveLetter\":  \"C\",\r\n    \"Offset\":  553648128,\r\n    \"PartitionNumber\":  4\r\n}"
              }
          ]
}
{
    "2":  [
              {
                  "1":  "{\r\n    \"DriveLetter\":  null,\r\n    \"Offset\":  17408,\r\n    \"PartitionNumber\":  1\r\n}"
              },
              {
                  "2":  "{\r\n    \"DriveLetter\":  \"D\",\r\n    \"Offset\":  135266304,\r\n    \"PartitionNumber\":  2\r\n}"
              }
          ]
}
```

The problem is that ConvertTo-Json creates a list/array inside the first key and a dictionary for each object inside that list, is there any way to overcome this?
The newline characters I can remove so that's not a big issue.
Here's how I want it to look:

```
{
        "0":
            "1":  {"DriveLetter": null, "Offset": 17408, "PartitionNumber": 1},
            "2":  {"DriveLetter": "F", "Offset": 135266304, "PartitionNumber": 2}
    }
    {
        "1":
            "1":  {"DriveLetter": null, "Offset": 1048576, "PartitionNumber":  1},
            "2":  {"DriveLetter": null, "Offset": 315621376, "PartitionNumber":  2},
            "3":  {"DriveLetter": null, "Offset": 419430400, "PartitionNumber":  3},
            "4":  {"DriveLetter": "C", "Offset": 553648128, "PartitionNumber":  4}
    }
    {
        "2": 
            "1":  {"DriveLetter": null, "Offset": 17408, "PartitionNumber": 1},
            "2":  {"DriveLetter": "D", "Offset": 135266304, "PartitionNumber": 2}
    }
```

Comment: That is the correct output though, the output you desire here isn't even proper JSON syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are currently 3 issues with your code.

First, you call `ConvertTo-Json` (at least) twice - once on the inner Partition hashtable and then again on the outer hashtable.

Second, you haven't specified the `Depth`, meaning that the inner dictionaries will be collapsed.

Lastly, you should use the partition number `$part` as the key of the second level of dictionaries if you want the output you describe:

```
foreach ($disk in (Get-Partition).DiskNumber | select -Unique | Sort-Object){
  ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3 @{
    "$disk" = foreach ($part in (Get-Partition -DiskNumber $disk).PartitionNumber | Sort-Object){
      @{
        "$part" = Get-Partition -DiskNumber $disk -PartitionNumber $part | ForEach-Object {
          @{
            PartitionNumber = $_.PartitionNumber;
            DriveLetter     = $_.DriveLetter;
            Offset          = $_.Offset
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above will produce `n` discrete JSON structures for `n` disks.

---

Move `ConvertTo-Json` outside the entire expression if you want a single structure with the disk array as the root object:

```
ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4 @(foreach ($disk in (Get-Partition).DiskNumber | select -Unique | Sort-Object){
  @{
    "$disk" = foreach ($part in (Get-Partition -DiskNumber $disk).PartitionNumber | Sort-Object){
      @{
        "$part" = Get-Partition -DiskNumber $disk -PartitionNumber $part | ForEach-Object {
          @{
            PartitionNumber = $_.PartitionNumber;
            DriveLetter     = $_.DriveLetter;
            Offset          = $_.Offset
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Great thanks that did the trick, I couldn't understand what -depth was used for, could have saved me some time.